# unlinked exchanges importing ecoinvent v.3.2 or 3.3 consequential versions with brightway

Tags: python-3.x, brightway

I am trying to import older versions of ecoinvent (3.2 and 3.3) and I get an error associated with unlinked exchanges. when doing :

```
bw.bw2setup()
bw.add_ecoinvent_33_biosphere_flows(version='33')
bw.create_default_lcia_methods(overwrite=True)

ei33consequential=bw.SingleOutputEcospold2Importer(path,"ei_33con")
ei33consequential.apply_strategies()
ei33consequential.statistics()
```

there's a message saying two exchanges could not be linked and were deleted (*residual wood, dry* and *venting of nitrogen, liquid*) this results in 123 unlinked exchanges and the impossibility to write the database.

I had a similar result with version 3.2 consequential (this time 4 exchanges deleted and 205 unlinked exchanges).

I tried version 3.4 and the deletion of exchanges did not result in unlinked exchanges so it works fine. With 3.3 cutoff also no problem.

Running the function

```
bw.add_ecoinvent_33_biosphere_flows()
```

did not add any biosphere flow.

Now that I know that v3.4 works, that's fine for me, but it could be problematic if for some reason we try to use older versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, the UUIDs of a few flows like `venting of nitrogen, liquid` changed from 3.3 to 3.4. Brightway tracks the latest version of the ecoinvent flows; you could subclass `Ecospold2BiosphereImporter` to point to a different metadata file, or add the obsolete flows to the Brightway base data in a pull request.